# C# static method

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a example of my book. From what i have read non static methods cant be used without instance a object of the class. So is this ok ?

```
public partial class TempAgencyForm : Form
{
     public TempAgencyForm()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void  btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        ...
        setVisibility(false);
     }

     private void  setVisibility(bool visibilityValue)
     {
         ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's really unclear what your question is here.

Comment: I see `static` once in your title, once in your question narrative, and not at all in your code sample. It's really not clear what you're attempting to ask.

Comment: A quick compile would have answered this, no?

Comment: If you are trying to call setVisibility() from btnCalculate_Click() then the answer is "Yes" this is ok.

Comment: We are not your compilers. If you're worried about the `setVisibility()` call, it's acutally calling `this.setVisibility()`, so it's operating on the current instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is fine. One non-static method can call another non-static method.

The call:

```
setVisibility(false);
```

can also be written:

```
this.setVisibility(false);
```

but the `this` qualifier is redundant.

However, if you had tried to call a non-static method without instance qualification from inside a **`static`** member, that would have been a problem (compile-time error).

Comment: *One non-static method can call another non-static method.* - that's a bit overly general, isn't it?

Comment: @Groo Can you elaborate? I try to give detalis on what I mean in the text following that line.

Comment: Yes, a non-static method can call a non-static method. But a non-static method *within the same class*, or a *non-static method of an already instantiated object*. A "non-static" method, public or not, cannot be called from anywhere unless an instance of that class is created. Meanwhile, a static method can also easily call a public instance method of any instantiated object (or a private instance method of its own parent class, if it instantiates it). And an instance method can easily call any public static method or private static method of its own parent class.

Comment: @Groo If the method name (identifier) is preceded with something, as in `Qualification.TheMethod(...);`, then we're outside the scope of this question, I assume. Non-static methods must use a concrete instance as the "qualification", and static methods use the type name (name of class or struct). This qualification can be left out only when calling a method from the same type (including inherited methods). For non-static methods, `this` is then used as the "default" qualifier. And `this` exists only in a non-static context. For `static` method, the current type name is the default "qualifier".

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about calling `setVisibility(false);`. Yes it is fine, neither it or the method calling it are static.

This will all happen within an instance of `TempAgencyForm`

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is okay, because it's called from within another member.

You're correct, since `setVisibility()` is not `static`, it always has to be called in the context of some object of the parent class (`TempAgencyForm` in this example).

However, `btnCalculate_Click()` is another member of `TempAgencyForm`, as such you're able to access the current/local object using the `this` keyword (`this.setVisibility()`), which is optional if there's no disambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

static or non static doesnt matter here, you are calling a member function declared within the same object. so short answer is "fine"

how you call TempAgencyForm members may be what you are referring to

in this case (as you have defined) instantiations is required

```
TempAgencyForm taf = new TempAgencyForm()
taf.setVisibility(false);
```

however if you have your class definition itself as static, i.e.

```
public static partial class TempAgencyForm
```

then,

```
TempAgencyForm.setVisibility(false);
```

is suffice (without instantiating the object) as the object is already loaded on stack at the time of application start

Comment: A static class can have no other base class than `object` (and can implement no interfaces), so your `static class` declaration is illegal.

Comment: agreed and  + 1 blind copy paste error :) (corrected now)